# why i am getting garbage sum in the inheritance program?

Tags: c++, inheritance

why i am getting garbage sum in the output using multilevel inheritance? The sum function is in the class `c` and object `c1` is created in main function.

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    int a, b;
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void input()
    {
        cout << "enter the values";
        cin >> a >> b;
    }
};
class C : public B {
public:
    void sum()
    {
        cout << a + b;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b1;
    C c1;
    b1.input();
    c1.sum();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code does an `input` on b1.  But does a `sum` and output of c1, which has undefined behavior because the member variables are uninitialized.  The `b1` and `c1` are two different objects, each has its own state.  I bet `b1.sum();` would produce a less surprising output.

Comment: The correct header is `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>` Also, avoid using `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 2):

> why i am getting garbage sum

Because the values you read in `b1.input()` are stored in a different object to what you print in `c1.sum()`.

You are adding uninitialised `int`s, so your program's behaviour is undefined.

Perhaps you want

```
int main()
{
    C c1;
    B & b1 = c1;
    b1.input();
    c1.sum();
    return 0;
}
```

Where you have a *reference* to the `B` base-subobject of your `C` object.

Or more simply

```
int main()
{
    C c1;
    c1.input();
    c1.sum();
    return 0;
}
```

Because a `C` *is* a `B`, you can call `B`'s methods with one.

Answer (score 0):

> why i am getting garbage sum

Because you read objects with indeterminate values.

The behaviour of the program is undefined.